# Select query with case depending one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have the following query:

```
Select Id, PosId from myTable
```

This return something like this:

> 1009, 2 or 1010,3 etc..

What I want to do is change PosId, for example if PosId = 2 change it to "Manager", etc. I'm trying to solve this using `CASE or If` but I don't know to much about use this in T-SQL, how can I solve this?

Here is what I tried

```
Select Id, 
Case When PosId = 2 then 'Manager' Else 0 End
From myTable
```

But with this I get

> Incorrect syntax near "Case"

Comment: Do you have a table that has the PosId and the description of what it means. That is typically how this kind of thing is done.

Comment: No, PosId doesn't have relationship with other tables.

Comment: The code you posted would not throw a syntax error unless it has some weird character from a copy/paste.  It would, however, throw a conversion error since you are using a numerical value and a string in the same case statement

Comment: If you don't know about how to update in sql server or how to use the case when syntax, the best place to start is google with a search of 'sql server update' or 'sql server case when'

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `CASE` syntax.  If anything, the error will be from different type of the `CASE` branches.  If one is `VARCHAR`, the other must also be `VARCHAR`

Comment: On the contrary, your case expression as posted will fail because you can't mix datatypes like that. You could use '0' as a string literal. The real question is why don't you have a table with the string representation of PosID? Without it you have a list of random numbers that have no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean mentioned, the cleanest way to do this would be to put the "lookup" in a table.

For example:

```
--Create the table
create table lookup
(
 posId int,
 description varchar(50)
);
insert into lookup values (1, 'Supervisor');
insert into lookup values (2, 'Manager');
insert into lookup values (3, 'Developer');
insert into lookup values (4, 'Janitor');
insert into lookup values (5, 'Mouse');
insert into lookup values (6, 'Dust');
insert into lookup values (7, 'Carpet');
insert into lookup values (8, 'Tester');
select * from lookup;
```

You can then use a simple select statement:

```
Select Id, description from myTable m
left outer join lookup l on m.PosId=l.posId
```

If you need help building the insert statements for the lookup table, I find it helpful to create a spreadsheet with the "insert into lookup values (" in the A column, the first lookup value "1" in the B column, the middle section ", '" in the C column, the second lookup value "Supervisor" in the D column, and the closing text "');" in the E column, then creating a "=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)" formula in the F column; then dragging down the formula to the end of your lookup list and finally copying your F column to a SQL Query window and executing it to actually insert these values in the table.

You could also use this excel concatenate technique to build your case statement "manually", which would look like this:

```
Select Id, 
Case 
 When PosId = 2 then 'Manager' 
 when PosId = 3 then 'Developer' 
Else 'No Value'
End
From myTable
```